Why is "display-buffer-reuse-window" producing an error?
Version: GNU Emacs 29.4 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.43,
cairo version 1.18.0)
I have an emacs configuration file which has followed me around through numerous different versions.  And I have set the variable display-buffer-alist as follows:
(setq display-buffer-alist
      '(("*R Dired"
     (display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-at-bottom)
     (window-width . 0.5)
     (window-height . 0.25)
     (reusable-frames . nil))
    ("*R"
     (display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-in-side-window)
     (side . left)
     (slot . -1)
     (window-width . 0.5)
     (reusable-frames . nil))
    ("*Help"
     (display-buffer-reuse-widndow display-buffer-in-side-window)
     (side . right)
     (slot . 1)
     (window-width . 0.5)
     (reusable-frames . nil))))

But whenever I attempt now to determine the value of a variable (with C-h v variable-name), I get the error:
Symbol's function definition is void: display-buffer-reuse-window

I'm not fully sure what's the problem here, or if I've misconfigured the display buffer as shown above.  Maybe I've defined the display buffers wrongly - in which case, where do I look for the correct way of doing it?  [I probably originally copied the definition from somewhere else, but that was too long ago...]  Anyway, many thanks!

Are you sure the error doesn't say widndow?  Because that's what your quoted code says.

Crikey - what a colossal idiot I am.  Had to go to all the trouble of making a long post here to have a simple typo pointed out to me.    Many thanks!
In fact the error probably did say widndow but I simply copied it out by hand and never noticed it.  Drat, bother, ...

I’m voting to close this question because it was on account of a typo and therefore won't be useful to other users.

... except perhaps as a warning that typos matter :-)
